# Can´t make violin chart appear in subplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

#Hi guys, I don´t know why the third plot below (violin) is not appearing in the third subplot space (it´s empty), could you pls assist?

#Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3)

fig.suptitle("Age Distribution", fontsize=15)

sns.distplot(insurance_ds["age"], ax=ax[0])

insurance_ds.boxplot(column=["age"], ax=ax[1])

sns.catplot(data=insurance_ds, kind="violin", y="age", ax=ax[2]) #->>>Not showing in third plot space
```

[subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMxsr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`catplot()` creates a new figure, and cannot be used to plot on a subplot.

You want to use [`sns.violinplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html?highlight=violinplot#seaborn.violinplot) directly.